# Would it be semantically incorrect to refer to a jQuery object containing one element as a node?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing docblock comments for a javascript library and I am wondering whether it reasonable to refer to a jQuery object containing a single element as a *node*.

And if it's not reasonable, then what would be concise alternative? For instance I have a method called `create_node()`, which for convenience returns a jQuery object, rather than the DOM node.

Comment: do you mean dom node?

Comment: @Robin yes, I've updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery object is an *object,* which contains (among other things) a single DOM node.

It's like calling the box which contains a new TV "the new TV", and in a technical context there's a functional difference.

As a developer, I would expect a function called `create_node` to return a literal DOM node, not a jQuery wrapper. I personally would go with something like `create_element`, as in an [HTML element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element), although that too [may be considered equivalent to "node"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element).

If you want to be unambiguous, try something like `create_jquery_element`.

Comment: I understand the difference, I've updated the question to ask for a concise alternative

Comment: Brilliant, thankyou! :) I think element is a more generic term and less misleading than node.

Answer (score 1):

No, since a jquery object is much more than the dom node and you can't invoke dom functions directly on it.

E.g.

```
$whatEverJqueryObject.getAttribute('name')
```

would fail.

Imho refering to it as dom node would just be confusing for the consumer of the library.

Answer (score 1):

A node wrapped in a jQuery object is not a node, it's a node wrapped in a jQuery object. If the documentation said that the function returns a node, I would be surprised to find that it was wrapped in a jQuery object.

However, once you have specified exactly what the function returns, from then on you could refer to the return value as "the node" without causing confusion.